# How to evaluate a for-comprehension to the last successful step in the chain?

Tags: scala, monads

Consider the following composition

```
for {
  v1 <- transform1(v)
  v2 <- transform2(v1)
  v3 <- transformThatErrors(v2)
  v4 <- transfrom4(v3)
} yield { v4 }
```

Is there a monad `M` that would allow for the above to evaluate to `M(v2)`?

I am trying to model a situation where the program should apply the full chain of transformations *until* the first transformation that fails, in which case the chain evaluates to the last successful transformation. In the worst case, the whole chain represents `identity(v)`.

Monads like `Either` and `Option` do not fit this requirement because on an error they evaluate the whole chain to an error, while it is required for the chain to always evaluate to success. In other words, I would like the program to try to do as much as it can, but if it cannot do anything, that is fine too.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the for comprehension syntax. I think you may be able to use `Either[T, T]`, ie. pass the failure value as the error.

Comment: I have a messy solution involving a combination of `Tuple2`, `Either`, `foldLeft`, pattern matching, and early `return`, however I was wondering if cat/scalaz provide out of the box solution.

Comment: It may help to include that code/the best parts of it. I've not seen it, but could be that there is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Either` monad *does* exactly what you want. Nothing in the interface of `Either` forces you to use different types for `Left` and `Right` case. In particular, the `Left` type parameter can be the same as the `Right` type parameter, they both can equal to something like `Result` (or "`PartialSuccess`"?), where you define what constitutes a `Result`.

Thus, you simply declare all your `transformN` functions to have return type

```
def transformN(previousStep: Result): Either[Result, Result] = ???
```

and in the very end, you `fold` it into a single result:

```
val res: Result = (for {
  v1 <- transform1(v)
  v2 <- transform2(v1)
  v3 <- transformThatErrors(v2)
  v4 <- transfrom4(v3)
} yield v4).fold(
  partialRes => partialRes,
  completeRes => completeRes
)
```

or even just

```
.fold(identity, identity)
```

As soon as the first transformation fails, the `Either` will package the partial result as a `Left`, and return it, without applying any further transformations. If every single transformation step succeeds, the very final result will be returned as `Right`. No matter at which point the transformation stops, the final `fold` will extract the (partial) result out of it.

If I understand it correctly, every other monad `M` you could possibly come up with, would be essentially the same as `Either[Result, Result]` with some special `getResult` method that is equivalent to `.fold(identity, identity)`, so there is no need to multiply entities unnecessarily.

Comment: `.merge` instead of `.fold(identity,identity)` makes it even shorter.

Comment: @MarioGalic oh, indeed! Never heard of it. Cool!